# Files added to config.assets.precompile are not served in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline, activeadmin

I am using the activeadmin gem which proposes a little weird way of including additional assets to those automatically generated by the gem:
https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/492

My problem however is that though in config/application.rb I do set

```
    config.assets.precompile += ['active_admin.css', 'active_admin.js', 'my.css', 'my.js']
```

my_file.css and my_file.js are not served in development mode, it's Routing error.

I have registered them with the activeadmin's own config.require_javascript and config.require_stylesheet, which seems to work, since generated html contains the respective script tags.

However the /assets/my.css and /assets/my.css are not responsive.

What could cause a problem, how do you think?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the files I was trying to add were corrupted somehow since creating the new ones and copying the content inside made a trick.

I was including the .js and .css files of this plugin:
http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/
which is fine not taking this issue into account.